# How to pass a loop cursor (current row) to another function/procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have to built some code around a loop and it's going to be huge. To make not more enemies than necessary I want to split up my code for the sake of readability.

My code looks like that:

```
FOR cur_tblA IN (SELECT col1, col2 FROM tblA) LOOP
  -- a lot of stuff
  NULL;
END LOOP;
```

Because the second line in real life is really a lot I want to pass my cursor `cur_tblA` to other functions. I expect that the value of `cur_tblA` is the current row and I can access the values like `cur_tblA.col1` etc. in my other function/procedure:

```
FUNCTION do_stuff(cur_tblA) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS BEGIN
    return cur_tblA.col1;
END do_stuff;
```

What is the right type for the signature for receiving`cur_tblA`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly with that type of cursor loop, but can use open/fetch with a record type defined in your package; something like:

```
TYPE rec_type IS RECORD (col1 tblA.col1%TYPE, col2 tblA.col2%TYPE);
```

Then in your main procedure declare a variable of that type and fetch into it:

```
rec rec_type;
...
OPEN cur_tblA FOR SELECT col1, col2 FROM tblA;
LOOP
  FETCH cur_tblA INTO rec
  EXIT WHEN cur_tblA%NOTFOUND;
  do_stuff(rec);
END LOOP;
```

The sub-function declaration would then be:

```
FUNCTION do_stuff(p_rec rec_type) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS BEGIN
  return p_rec.col1;
END do_stuff;
```

You could also define and pass a collection of records, if that is appropriate for your further processing. And the procedures/functions don't necessarily all have to be in the same package - you can refer to `your_package.rec_type`, if the type is declared publicly in the package specification. Though in this case it sounds like they will all be together.